# Enter Date into SQL Backup Name

Tags: t-sql

I'm creating a script where it will backup all my DB's in the order I tell it to, but I'd like the backup name to be 'DATABASENAME_TodaysDate.bak'.
I have tried using this T-SQL:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASENAME] TO  DISK = N'D:\Backups\DatabaseName_getdate()_.bak'
```

I then realised this wouldn't work as the `GETDATE()` is inside the apostrophes.

Comment: Create the path string in you want in a variable and and use the variable instead of a string. Even at `dba.stackexchange.com` this question will be closed quickly as it doesn't show an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `GETDATE()` function outside the apostrophes by using e.g. the function `CONCAT()`. Example:

`BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASENAME] TO DISK = CONCAT('D:\Backups\DatabaseName_', GETDATE(), '_.bak');`

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it, is the following:

```
        SELECT @DateString = CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4))
                           + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
                           + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2);
        SELECT @TimeString = RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
                           + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2);
        SELECT @SQL = 'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @Database + ']'
                    + ' TO DISK = ''' + @BackupDir + '\' + @Database + '_' + @BackupType 
                    + '_' + @DateString + '_'+ @TimeString + @BackupFileSuffix + ''''
                    + ' WITH INIT';

        -- Backup Database
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC (@SQL);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            --do something usefull here like sending an email
        END CATCH
```

It's ugly, i know. But it works for us

EDIT: Because our solution is ugly, here something "not that ugly"

```
declare @sql varchar (400) = concat('BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASENAME] TO DISK = ''D:\Backups\DatabaseName_', format(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss'), '_.bak''');
select @sql
```